# AWS SNS Notifications to multiple users without topics

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, push-notification, amazon-sns

I have been using Parse for a year now to send notifications to my android app. As they will be retiring their services soon I want to move to Amazon SNS.

I have tried it out and successfully received GCM. But the problem is that Parse allowed me to send an array of Installations Ids (Registration Ids) in one http request and in Amazon I was not able to find anything like that except Topics. I just want to know is Topics the only way to send to multiple devices in single http request or is there any API like Parse supported sending an array of Installation Ids (Registration Ids). Thanks.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out as well... I want to know if its better to subscribe 500 users to a topic then send a push to the topic, or is it better to send 500 pushes individually..

Comment: It depends, as if you want the notification to be sent as quickly as possible to all of your user base or you don't mind it. If you care about the how quickly it's being sent then use topics otherwise individual Notifications would do but remember these are 500 separate http calls rather than one in case of topics. In case its promotional notification use topics and in case of its being transactional use individual calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after some googling the answer is no. No, you can't send same message in single request to multiple users unless you use topics.